# Report failure from nodejs module initialization function

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I have a nodejs C++ module and I would like to understand how to report initialization errors. So the boilerplate for this is:

```
extern "C" void Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> instance)
{
    // Do initialization stuff
}

NODE_MODULE(SomeModuleType, Initialize)
```

How can I report an error inside `Initialize` if it has no return type and I am not allowed to throw since it is `extern "C"`? Is there some specific callback that I should call?

Also, what is the best practice to report errors from the callback methods exposed to nodejs? Is returning null objects the common practice or can I throw there and that would show as an exception on the javascript side?

Comment: The `extern "C"` doesn't mean you can't use C++ specific code and statements like `throw`, it just means that there is no [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Well, I'd agree only partially. If the caller is C code it would lead to UB.

Comment: Considering that it's doubtful a nodejs module would ever be loaded by a C application, chances for that is slim to none. For starters, a non-C++ application can't pass the correct argument to the function.

Comment: Ok, true, my consent was more of a general nature. Anyhow, I hope someone familiar with the nodejs plugin system can then tell is there a special exception that I should throw or if `std::exception` is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

After lurking around nodejs sources I came down to this, however comments are still welcome, about if this is a good approach:

```
extern "C" void Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> instance)
{
    try
    {
        // Do something unsafe
    }
    catch (std::exception& Exception)
    {
        node::Environment::GetCurrent(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())->ThrowError("module initialization failed");
    }
}
```

If I simply rethrow the exception then under the debugger the execution goes on which is not what I want.